# Sum a Column result in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I fed a CSV file to the Logstash, which looks like below:

data value result

d1    v1   12

d2    v2    1

d3    v3    4

I want a sum of "result" column in a single variable or as a extra column in CSV.

**Total

17**

Kindly Help...!!!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? A `sum` field for each row seems odd, unless it's summing data within that row. If you want a sum that takes each event into account, you might want to set that up in Elasticsearch, Statsd, or some other aggregator.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your data split into explicit fields, you'd want to go with the sum aggregator:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html